# Using numpy array_split() to get desired split-size that is not a sub-multiple

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of bytes, of size 268238. (dtype="uint8")
How can i split these into subarrays with size 2211 each?
The remainder array can be smaller.

In general: I try to split files in chunks of size 2211 bytes with numpy for some reason.
(Additional info: After that i want to base64_encode all of these 2211 elements in the array, but this only for your additional information)

```
# create an array to test the problem
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(255, size=268238).astype("uint8")
# check size and dtype.
a.size
a.dtype
# until now everything is fine
# now i want to split it in equal parts of 2211 elements
# last one may be smaller
# 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html
# just take the elements size now... 
(np.array_split(a, a.size // 2211))[0].size # <-- 2217... but why?
(np.array_split(a, a.size // 2211))[1].size # <-- 2217... but why?
# ...
(np.array_split(a, a.size // 2211))[120].size # <-- 2216 (remainder..)
```

Is there an error in the `numpy.array_split` method?

I've expected every chunk to be 2211 elements (2211 numbers of uint8). Instead, I get a chunk size of 2217 elements.
It doesn't matter if I use 119, 120, 121 or 122 as argument to `array_split`. I still don't get the chunk size of 2211.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

** EDIT: **
This is doing the job, but the question needs to be answered,
why the array_split is behaving as not expected. Can someone explain it?

```
out = [a[i : i + 2211] for i in range(0, len(a), 2211)]
out[121].size
#  707 <-- the correct remainder
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) on `array_split()` says that instead of passing the size of each fragment to the `array_split()` function, you also have the option of passing the indices where you want the split to occur.
Using this idea, the following code will give you the result you're looking for:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(255, size=268238).astype("uint8")
split_positions = list(range(2211,268238,2211))
split_result = np.array_split(a, split_positions)
frag_size_list = [p.size for p in split_result]
print (frag_size_list)
```

The output of this is:

```
[2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 2211, 707]
```

The reason why your code was not working has got to do with the arithmetic involved. You will realize it if you try to use your fragment size to re-compute your original size.

To elaborate further on why your code did not work:

```
268238 /  2211 = 121.3198
268238 // 2211 = 121
```

You are passing `121` as the number of fragments, to the `array_split()` function. But will that produce the frag-size of `2211` that you are looking for? The below arithmetic says that it won't:

`268238 / 121 = 2216.843` (which is approximately `2217`).